# How can I send money go the app user via paypal or credit-card?

Tags: android, paypal, credit-card

I have an application which user play some games and earn scores and after that, they can earn money, according to their sum od scores.

The problem is, I don't know how should I integrate this method (sending money to the user) with my app. I both have Visa card and business `paypal` account and to be honest, I wanna have both of them in my app. although I have read previous posts in `stackoverflow` about this thing, I haven't reached to my answer.

Please help me in details, if possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [Payouts API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites#get-access-to-paypal-payouts) or the [Hyperwallet service](https://www.hyperwallet.com/) could fit your use case.

Either would require approval by PayPal. You need to apply to use them and explain your business use case.